# Windows Phone XNA: Real Time Strategy Camera

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

We are developing a real time strategy varient for WP7. At the momment, we require some direction/instruction on how to build an effective camera system. In other words, we would like a camera that can pan around a flat surface (2d or 3d level map). We have been experimenting with a 2d tile map, while our unit/characters are all 3d models.

At first glance, it appears we need to figure out how to calculate a bounding box around the camera and its entire view perspective. Or, restrict the movement of the camera to what it can see, to the bounds of a 2d map.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing true 2D scrolling, it's pretty simple:

- Scroll.X must be between 0 and level.width - screen.width
- Scroll.Y must be between 0 and level.height - screen.height

(use `MathHelper.Clamp` to help you with this)

As for 3D it's a little trickier but almost the same principle.

All you really need is to define TWO `Vector3` points, one is the lower left back corner and the other the upper right front (or you could do upper left front / lower right back, etc., up to you). These would be your bounding values.

The first one you could define as a `readonly` with just constant values that you tweak the camera bounds exactly as you wish for that corner. There IS a way of computing this, but honestly I prefer to have more control so I typically choose the route of value tweaking instead.

The second one you could start off with a "base" that you could manually tweak (or compute) just like before but this time you have to add the map width and length (to X and Z) so you know the true bounds depending on the map you have loaded.

Once you have these values, clamp them just as before:

```
    //pans the camera but caps at bounds
    public void ScrollByCheckBounds(Vector3 scroll, Vector3 bottomLeftFront, Vector3 topRightBack)
    {
        Vector3 newScroll = Scroll + scroll;

        //clamp each dimension
        newScroll.X = MathHelper.Clamp(newScroll.X, topRightBack.X, bottomLeftFront.X);
        newScroll.Y = MathHelper.Clamp(newScroll.Y, topRightBack.Y, bottomLeftFront.Y);
        newScroll.Z = MathHelper.Clamp(newScroll.Z, bottomLeftFront.Z, topRightBack.Z);
        Scroll = newScroll;
    }
```